# Why $Q_i=Q'_i$ for $I=⋂_{i=1}^mQ_i'=⋂_{i=1}^nQ_i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I am studying the theorem:

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain of dimension $1$. Then every non-zero ideal $I$ of $R$ has a unique expression as a product of primary ideals with distinct radicals.

Proof. Let $I=⋂_{i=1}^nQ_i$  such that $Q_i$ are primary and each $P_i=rad (Q_i )$ is maximal since $R$ is of dimension 1. Since no $P_i⊆P_j$ for $i≠j$ then $P_i$ are embedded primes and hence the $Q_i$ are unique. The $P_i$ are pairwise comaximal ($P_i+P_j=R$ for all $i≠j$) whence so are the $Q_i$. It follows  that $Q_1∩…∩Q_n=Q_1…Q_n$.

Conversely if $I=Q_1'…Q_m'$ where $Q_i'$ are primary with distinct nilradicals nilrad $Q_i'$. As before the $Q_i'$ are comaximal, so $I=∏_{i=1}^mQ_i' =⋂_{i=1}^mQ_i'$ . By uniqueness of decomposition, $m=n$ and $Q_i=Q_i'$ after permuting.

I am not understanding why $Q_i=Q'_i$ for $I=⋂_{i=1}^mQ_i'=⋂_{i=1}^nQ_i$? 
Would you help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it should say "...hence the $Q_i$ are *distinct*."  Also, everywhere you've said nilradical, I think you just mean radical.  The nilradical is the radical of the zero ideal.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Thank you for your reply. I mean why do we obtain that $Q_i=Q'_i$ for two distinct representations of I?

Comment: The uniqueness of the $Q_i$ follows from the so-called *Second Uniqueness Theorem*.